# Setting the timeouts on fadein/fadeut jQuery

Tags: jquery, settimeout, fadeout

I have a msg alert that shows up on select change or ajax request. 
It works partial ok but the issue is that if you switch between the options fast 
You will see fadeout/fadein again even the msg is already visible.

The desired effect is , if msg is visible and new msg comes in,  clear existing timeout, set new msg timeout and than fade out. 
**http://jsfiddle.net/p2979/1/**

```
function alerts(msg) {

    $('.msg-alert').fadeIn(500).html(msg);

    if ($('.msg-alert').is(':visible')) {
        $('.msg-alert').delay(2000).fadeOut(500);
    }
}


$('#option').on('change', function () {


    if ($(this).val() == 1) {
        var msg = 'Msg 1';
    } else {
        msg = 'Msg 2';
    }

    alerts(msg);
});
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use stop, and add function inside fadeOut() to add the html msg like this

```
function alerts(msg) {
    $('.msg-alert').stop().fadeOut(500, function () {
        $('.msg-alert').html(msg)
    }).fadeIn(500)
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/p2979/4/)

**Update**

You can use clearInterval() and setTimeout like this

```
var tOut = null;

function alerts(msg) {
    clearTimeout(tOut);
    $this = $('.msg-alert');
    $this.html(msg).fadeIn(500);
    tOut = setTimeout(function () {
        $this.fadeOut(500);
    }, 2000);
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/p2979/8/)

Comment: this one does not fade out anymore

Comment: @Benn does not fade out? fades out for me

Comment: Ah now i see you want it to fadeout after 2 seconds after it's shown

Comment: The desired effect is this.  Msg fades in , you switch , msg text changes only and new timeout starts for fadeout,2sec in it fades out, Magnus almost had it but it fades in/out on each switch

Comment: Almost again , check that function , the timeout clears it , soo second msg stays for half a sec and it should have started own time, 2 sec again. Switch fast 3 times and you will see it

Answer (score 0):

Add `.stop()` before your `.fadeIn()` to clear the previous animation queue.

```
$('.msg-alert').stop().fadeIn(500).html(msg);
```

It usually takes care of all queueing quirks that happens when you are working with triggered animations.

And you can add your `.fadeOut()` to the callback of `.fadeIn()`.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/p2979/9/)**

Comment: Added a demo to my answer where I also put the `.fadeOut()` in the callback of `.fadeIn()`.

Comment: This is almost it , what bugs me is that there is fadeout/fadein on each switch , if msg div is visible , the msg should change only , and new timeout should start